# Default naming Convention of Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class ThreadNaming extends Thread {
    public void run(){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
public static void main(String args[]){
    Thread t1 = new ThreadNaming();
    Thread t2 = new ThreadNaming();
    t1.start();
    System.out.println(t1);
    t2.start();
    System.out.println(t2);
    }
}
```

Output: 
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
Thread-0
Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
Thread-1

```
public class ThreadOddNaming extends Thread {
    public void run(){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
public static void main(String args[]){ 
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new ThreadOddNaming());
    Thread t4 = new Thread(new ThreadOddNaming());
    t3.start();
    t4.start();
    System.out.println(t3);
    System.out.println(t4);
}
}
```

Output:
Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
Thread-3
Thread-1
Thread[Thread-3,5,main]

Now, I have two questions.

1. When Thread is created with new keyword with class name(extending Thread) constructor, then thread naming is whole number begins with 0, 1, 2, 3 .. (n-1).
   But when it is created directly with Thread constructor passing class name (extending Thread) as argument, then thread naming is odd number begins with 1,3,5..(2n-1)

Why this behavior is shown or whether it is constant for a platform?
(I ran this program in windows system). 
Or, it may show different behavior for different platforms?

2. Whenever we print any thread object, why the priority of the thread is always 5.

Default priority that is assigned to a thread is NORM_PRIORITY. 
So, is 5 the value of NORM_PRIORITY?

Comment: Because `new Thread(new ThreadOddNaming())` creates two Thread instances.

Answer (score 1):

> When Thread is created with new keyword with class name(extending Thread) constructor, then thread naming is whole number begins with 0, 1, 2, 3 .. (n-1). But when it is created directly with Thread constructor passing class name (extending Thread) as argument, then thread naming is odd number begins with 1,3,5..(2n-1)

This is because

`Thread t3 = new Thread(new ThreadOddNaming());`

`Thread t4 = new Thread(new ThreadOddNaming());`

Creates a total of 4 threads. That's why you're seeing this behavior.

> Whenever we print any thread object, why the priority of the thread is always 5.

Because the default priority for the Thread class is NORM_PRIORITY.

`public final static int NORM_PRIORITY = 5;`

You can see this in Thread's source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#243).

Keep in mind though that the priority of the newly created thread always takes the same priority of it's creator. So if you had a priority 4 thread create a new thread, then the new one would be priority 4 unless set otherwise using `setPriority()`

Cheers!